# Integrar Keycloak ao Auth0

Tags: autenticação, auth, integração, sso

Gostaria de saber se é possível configurar no auth0 um SSO (single sign on) customizado.

A ideia é utilizar o keycloak como IDP (identity provider).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa imagem é possível visualizar os tipos de logins habilitados, "Username-Password-Authetication" é o login através de usuário e senha e "google-oauth2" é o login através do serviço do google.

Novamente: É possível adicionar um 'login social' através do keycloak?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver essa dúvida da seguinte forma:

1. Na aba Authentication no canto esquerdo, tem a opção Social.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Clique em criar conexão e digite apenas um caracter, pode ser qualquer um, que vai aparecer a opção de criar uma conexão customizada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Depois disso é só configurar os endpoints de acordo com o keycloak que funcionou perfeitamente o login.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]